# Creating dictionary keys with substrings from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe with a column that includes the names of boroughs in New York City (Manhattan, Brooklyn, etc.). I want to create another column, 'borough_num', that assigns a number for each borough (Manhattan -> 1, Brooklyn -> 2, Queens -> 3, Staten Island -> 4, Bronx -> 5, Other -> 0).

However, in the Borough column, some rows contain numbers in front of the borough name (e.g. instead of "Bronx" I have "07 Bronx"). Because this "07 Bronx" is still part of the Bronx borough, it should also be assigned to the same value "5" as "Bronx". I therefore need to create a dictionary that assigns the number 5 to a string that **contains** the word "Bronx". The same for each Borough. Any clue on how to do this? I am new to python!

This is what I had before noticing the cells with the numbers:

```
df['Borough'] = df['Borough'].fillna('OTHER')
borough_dict = {'MANHATTAN':1, 'BROOKLYN':2, 'QUEENS': 3, 'STATEN ISLAND': 4, 'BRONX': 5, 'OTHER':6}
df['borough_num'] = df['Borough'].apply(lambda x:0 if borough_dict.get(x) == None else borough_dict.get(x))
```

[image]

Comment: you can use `str.__contains__('BRONX')` or `regex expressions`

Comment: What you're looking for are regular expressions. Look at the `re` module in python (included in all base installs) and use https://regex101.com/ to play around with your expression. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is a small set of borough names for which to assign the integer codes, it's perfectly acceptable to do it as a series of explicit logical index assignments, such as with some example data below.

Specifically, there is no need in this case to try to encapsulate the borough-to-code mapping into a `dict` or a helper function or any fancier `apply` or `map` operation on the DataFrame.

Just a set of 5 boring, direct logical assignments.

```
In [13]: df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'Borough': ["Manhattan", "Brooklyn", "Bronx", "07 Bronx", 
                "109 Staten Island", "03 Brooklyn", "04 Queens"], 
    'Value':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
})

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
             Borough  Value
0          Manhattan      1
1           Brooklyn      2
2              Bronx      3
3           07 Bronx      4
4  109 Staten Island      5
5        03 Brooklyn      6
6          04 Queens      7

In [15]: df['Borough_num'] = 6  # everything defaults to the 'other' case

In [16]: df.loc[df.Borough.str.contains("Manhattan"), 'Borough_num'] = 1

In [17]: df.loc[df.Borough.str.contains("Brooklyn"), 'Borough_num'] = 2

In [18]: df.loc[df.Borough.str.contains("Queens"), 'Borough_num'] = 3

In [19]: df.loc[df.Borough.str.contains("Staten Island"), 'Borough_num'] = 4

In [20]: df.loc[df.Borough.str.contains("Bronx"), 'Borough_num'] = 5

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
             Borough  Value  Borough_num
0          Manhattan      1            1
1           Brooklyn      2            2
2              Bronx      3            5
3           07 Bronx      4            5
4  109 Staten Island      5            4
5        03 Brooklyn      6            2
6          04 Queens      7            3
```

If you want to encapsulate the borough-to-code mapping for whatever reason, you can do it with a simple `dict` followed by a loop:

```
In [30]: borough_code = {'Manhattan': 1, 'Brooklyn': 2, 'Queens': 3,
                         'Staten Island': 4, 'Bronx': 5}

In [31]: for borough, code in borough_code.items():
    ...:     df.loc[df.Borough.str.contains(borough), 'Borough_num'] = code
```

Unless the DataFrame is gigantic, the repeated vectorized calculation of `str.contains` will be indistinguishable from mapping a function across the column, but will be much easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks! However, if the number of boroughs were to be longer (say 50), should I just create a function like Victor Valente suggested?

Comment: Rather than a function, I would create a `dict`, and then change the enumerated 5 assignments into a for-loop over the `dict` that makes the assignments. I would see zero reason to do this with a mapped function unless the DataFrame is gigantic or the set of unique boroughs is a gigantic fraction of the length of DataFrame.

Comment: I get this error: KeyError: '[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0] not in index'

Comment: @AlexLaval I would have to see your full code to know why. The code as-is from my answer does not produce that error. Likely you are using the wrong variable as if it is a `dict` key somewhere.

Comment: I think the second version of the code in this answer is what you'd almost always want, whether for the 5 boroughs of Manhattan or all 62 counties of New York or some not-even-static set of data.

Comment: Also, I like the way you raised the performance cost of repeated vectorizing then explained why it's probably not important—if this really is a bottleneck in someone's code, that probably is something they want to take a quick look at, so it's worth knowing about, but it's rarely going to be relevant.

Comment: The second solution here should be the accepted answer, given OP already has a `dict`.

Comment: @ely can I send you the code? Even with the second answer I get errors

Comment: @AlexLaval Just add it as an update to your question and notify me when you do. Please make sure to add all the relevant code, not just the specific lines that implement the second approach, because the bug might be in a variable assignment elsewhere, etc. And include whatever error traceback you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe write a simple helper function:

```
def find_borough_id(name):
    for k, v in borough_dict.items():
        if k in name:
            return v
    return 0

df['borough_num'] = df['Borough'].apply(find_borough_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to search which key of borough_dict is a substring of x and returns its associated value:

```
def get_borough_num(x):
  for key, val in borough_dict.items():
    if key in x:
       return val
  return 0
df['borough_num'] = df['Borough'].apply(get_borough_num)
```

---

An alternative solution is to assume that all rows use as borough_name the borough name or endswith a space + the borough name. With such assumption, you can get the borough_name using:

```
x.rsplit(' ')[-1]
```

which returns the string after the last space if the string contains a space or the whole string otherwise:

```
"Manhattan".rsplit(' ')[-1] => "Manhattan"
"blah Manhattan".rsplit(' ')[-1] => "Manhattan"
```

so when ends up with:

```
get_borough_num = lambda x: borough_dict.get(x.rsplit(' ')[-1], 0)
df['borough_num'] = df['Borough'].apply(get_borough_num)
```

Comment: Thank you! The first alternative (the function) didn't quite work in my dataframe as it would assign the wrong values. The second one works better, but it still assigns some random values (I have one row with Saten Island, and it has assigned it a value of 0 instead of 4). Any clue why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Let's use Pandas str accessor and string functions such as `extract`, `join`, `upper` and python method `map`.

Given setup from @alexlaval question:

```
borough_dict = {'MANHATTAN':1, 'BROOKLYN':2, 'QUEENS': 3, 'STATEN ISLAND': 4, 'BRONX': 5, 'OTHER':6}
```

and setup from @ely

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Borough': ["Manhattan", "Brooklyn", "Bronx", "07 Bronx", 
                "109 Staten Island", "03 Brooklyn", "04 Queens","Unknown"], 
    'Value':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
})
```

Let's create a regex to extract boroughs from dataframe column:

```
x = '(' + '|'.join(borough_dict.keys()) + ')'
```

Now, let's use extract and map to get borough number

```
df['Borough_number'] = df.Borough.str.upper()\
                         .str.extract(x, expand=False).fillna('OTHER')\
                         .map(borough_dict)
```

Output:

```
             Borough  Value  Borough_number
0          Manhattan      1               1
1           Brooklyn      2               2
2              Bronx      3               5
3           07 Bronx      4               5
4  109 Staten Island      5               4
5        03 Brooklyn      6               2
6          04 Queens      7               3
7            Unknown      8               6
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive way to do it is to define a function to search for a string and if that string is found, then return the intended id.

```
def borough_id(borough):
    if 'Bronx' in borough:
        return 5
    elif ...
        ...
        ...
    else:
        return None

df['borough_num'] = df['Borough'].apply(lambda x: borough_id(x))
```

Comment: Not me, but that's only because I have no votes left today. This is extremely inefficient and not scalable.

Comment: Hey Victor, I'm not sure. I just created a profile to ask this question, so I have no authority to vote yet. Thank you for the advice though!

Comment: I also didn't downvote. While I believe setting up a helper function to use via `apply` is overkill for this problem, I don't believe that should warrant any downvotes. Don't take it personally. Many questions involving tools like Pandas suffer from the problem of "the fights are so bitter because the stakes are so low." There's a lot of punitive downvoting just based on mere preference, or totally spurious performance criteria that have zilch to do with the question at hand. Your answer is perfectly normal and fine in 99% of cases.

Comment: @ely, I respect your opinion, but this is more about `python`, in fact more to do with *data structure* choice. Maintaining a nested `if` / `else` construct, even for ~5 items (as in here) isn't *ideal* when a dictionary solution is possible. Nothing to do with `pandas` in my opinion.

Comment: @jpp The question is solely about pandas syntax, and certainly not about data structure code golf. It's just a boring business logic question about integer coding of data. These questions pop up all the time and almost never have any connection to efficient data structure choices or other generalizations.

Comment: @ely, Well, IMHO that's a mistake. **Data structure choice** is absolutely critical. It's not something you should brush over as irrelevant because the post is tagged `[pandas]`; in fact, if you use `pandas` you should be *even more cognisant* of underlying data structures (since they are often hidden away).

Comment: @ely, FYI, not my downvote (but I've already said that). We'll agree to disagree. There will *always* be 2 camps on this.

Comment: @ely, So it's "the ignorant, the right, and the wrong" - how open-minded!

Comment: @jpp I'll repeat it here - your dict solutions are misguided, given that you perform a linear lookup beforehand.

Comment: @miradulo, My point isn't just about performance. I *know* it's a linear lookup. But I'd much rather have a linear look-up in a dictionary than a dozen `if` / `elif` / `else` clauses.

Comment: @jpp Looks to me like you're just needlessly adding overhead and confusion. If you want to use a dict, ely's answer (with one linear lookup) seems like the best way.

Answer (score -2):

**Object-oriented approach**

You can subclass `dict` and then use `pd.Series.map`.

```
class dict_endswith(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, value):
        key = next((k for k in self.keys() if value.endswith(k)), None)
        return self.get(key)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Borough': ['07 BRONX', '01 MANHATTAN', 'STATEN ISLAND', '12 QUEENS', 'UNKNOWN']})

d = dict_endswith({'MANHATTAN':1, 'BROOKLYN':2, 'QUEENS': 3, 'STATEN ISLAND': 4, 'BRONX': 5, 'OTHER':6})

df['borough_num'] = df['Borough'].map(lambda x: d[x]).fillna('OTHER')

print(df)

#          Borough borough_num
# 0       07 BRONX           5
# 1   01 MANHATTAN           1
# 2  STATEN ISLAND           4
# 3      12 QUEENS           3
# 4        UNKNOWN       OTHER
```

Comment: This completely defeats the point of a dict though. Now you have linear lookup.

Comment: @miradulo. Linear look is not, in itself, bad. If performance is an issue, OP would note.

Comment: Indeed linear is fine. But creating a not-so-useful dict subclass just to do this one particular linear lookup seems.. odd.

Answer (score -2):

**Functional approach**

Use a custom function with a generator expression, and make use of the default value of `dict.get` to return 'OTHER' if no match is found.

Then apply the function via `pd.Series.apply`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Borough': ['07 BRONX', '01 MANHATTAN', 'STATEN ISLAND', '12 QUEENS', 'UNKNOWN']})

d = {'MANHATTAN':1, 'BROOKLYN':2, 'QUEENS': 3, 'STATEN ISLAND': 4, 'BRONX': 5, 'OTHER':6}

def map_borough(x, mapping):
    return mapping.get(next((k for k in mapping if x.endswith(k)), None), 'OTHER')

df['borough_num'] = df['Borough'].apply(map_borough, mapping=d)

print(df)

#          Borough borough_num
# 0       07 BRONX           5
# 1   01 MANHATTAN           1
# 2  STATEN ISLAND           4
# 3      12 QUEENS           3
# 4        UNKNOWN       OTHER
```

Answer (score -2):

**Loopy solution**

If you want to use a loop, then make your code more readable by separating data structure from logic.

In this example, you can iterate your dictionary items sequentially. [@ely's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49909340/9209546) is better for a larger dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Borough': ['07 BRONX', '01 MANHATTAN', 'STATEN ISLAND', '12 QUEENS', 'UNKNOWN']})

d = {'MANHATTAN':1, 'BROOKLYN':2, 'QUEENS': 3, 'STATEN ISLAND': 4, 'BRONX': 5, 'OTHER':6}

def map_borough(x, mapping):
    for k, v in mapping.items():
        if k in x:
            return v
    else:
        return 'OTHER'

df['borough_num'] = df['Borough'].apply(map_borough, mapping=d)

#          Borough borough_num
# 0       07 BRONX           5
# 1   01 MANHATTAN           1
# 2  STATEN ISLAND           4
# 3      12 QUEENS           3
# 4        UNKNOWN       OTHER
```